# How to check if a post already exist on the page before refreshing and appending new posts in Using jQuery • 43 minutes ago

Tags: php, jquery, html

Guys I will appreciate your kind guidance on this please.
I'm building a forum page on my website with functionalities for posts/comments.

Here's the fetch post part of my jquery file:

```
function fetchPosts(){
      var url = "fetch_posts.php";
      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, user){
                  if ($("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']").exists()){
                     var postHtml = '<div class="col-md-1"><img src="images/user.png" alt="image" width="50px" height="50px" background="#FC6806"></div><div class="col-md-11"><h5 style="color:#FC6806"><strong>'+user.name+'</strong></h5><h6 style="color:#FC6806">'+user.time+'</h6><h5 style="color:#0269C2"><strong>'+user.topic+'</strong></h5><p data-     id="'+user.id+'">'+user.post+'</p></div><br/>';
                      $("#comment_thread").append(postHtml);
                  }
            });
      });
}
fetchPosts();  
setInterval(fetchPost, 5000);
```

Now I wrote a function of setInterval that refreshes the page every 5s.

The effect of that is that each time it does, it appends all the posts as fetched from the database again, and that goes on and on and on.

What I want to incorporate is that each time the page refreshes, there should be a check of the posts id of the posts fetched and any one on the page already should not be appended, while new ones should be appended.

I tried selecting the children and then check to see if any one has a data-id attribute of the post id currently on the page but I'm getting an error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...).exists is not a function"
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Don't use .append(), but .html() to replace it with new, not spawn infinite old and new one. You can also check if update is needed. Create MD5 sum in your json and check if it has changed. But for as often updates the best would be reactjs not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @Zydnar. using .html did not work for me. It outputs nothing to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** to see if a jQuery selector returns matches

```
if ($("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']").length){
```

Comment: Thanks @ Charlietfl..using `if ($("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']").length){` did not output anything on the screen.

Comment: we have no idea what your html looks like or what `user` looks like

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']")` returns null. You should use `if ($("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']").length > 0) {` to check if it's on the page.

Comment: Thanks @Styphon..using `if ($("#comment_thread").children("p[data-id='"+user.id+"']").length > 0) {` returns a blank screen. What could be wrong?